# Field/Input label based on record in react admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, recompose

I'd like part of the record to be included in the label for a BooleanField (and BooleanInput).  I'm trying to use WithProps to accomplish this.

If I use

```
<BooleanField source="FileSystem" label="FileSystem" />
```

This seems to work just fine.  If, instead I try to wrap it

```
const makeLabel = (props)=>{
    let label = `Filesystem for ${props.record.id}`;

    return {label};
}

const withLabel = withProps(makeLabel);
const BooleanFieldWithLabel = compose(withLabel)((props)=>{
    console.log("props after compose",props);
    return <BooleanField {...props}/>
});
```

And then use `<BooleanFieldWithLabel source="FileSystem" />` It doesn't render any label.  I've tried a few different ways and nothing seems to work even though I can see in the console.log that the correct label is in props.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question, I cannot display the label base on field's value on "Show" page.
From react-admin source code, it seems only I set "addLabel" prop on the direct child of "SimpleShowLayout" or "TabbedShowLayout", then I can see label on my custom field.

### But it is not configurable, I want to show/hide label base on field's value. Do I need to implement my own custom "SimpleShowLayout" or "TabbedShowLayout"? Or is there any better approaches?

Update my post.
I just figure out the solution by implementing an HOC like below. I am wondering is there any better approaches to implement the same feature?

```js
import React from "react";
    import get from "lodash/get";
    import { TextField, DateField, Labeled } from "react-admin";

    const NullableField = WrappedComponent => props => {
      const { record, source } = props;
      const value = get(record, source);
      return value ? (
        <Labeled {...props}>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </Labeled>
      ) : null;
    };
    const NullableTextField = NullableField(TextField);
    const NullableDateField = NullableField(DateField);
    export { NullableTextField, NullableDateField };
```

Comment: @raju_eww Thanks for you advise, I just updated my code.